# Post app download: image download

Tags: android, image

How can I post load the images for my app after and only if the user wants when the app has been downloaded from the market?

I’ve seen post downloading done, just don’t know where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to host the image files on a server.
In your app on the launch activity just do a file check for the required images in your private data directory.
If they are not present , then download them.
Make sure downloading is done in a background task with a dialog that enables you to cancel.
If they are large , consider adding the permission to keep the screen alive also.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should start downloading image on boot time. So that when someone open your application for the first time all images will be downloaded from server to your application.
Here is a link to execute your code at boot time.

http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/06/start-service-at-boot/